# URL rewrite not working for one URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Those lines are working for wordpress but `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R=301]` is not redirecting when I open `www.example.com/foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Order of RewriteRule matters** in .htaccess. Change your .htaccess code to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /bar [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: that helped. but again (sorry) `RewriteRule ^foo/test$ /bar [L,R=301] ` is not redirecting, I have folder named 'foo' but not test.

Comment: So you have `RewriteRule ^foo/test$ /bar [L,R=301]` May I know if this is the only .htaccess you have and what URI you're typing in browser?

Comment: using that in place of `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /bar [L,R=301]` and URL is `www.example.com/foo/test`

Comment: Can you pls also tell me if you have any other .htaccess on your system? If not then can you pls copy/paste your access.log and error.log snippet for this request.

Comment: There is nothing in logs for this as 'page not found' is displaying from wordress. There is no other htaccess.

Comment: I don't get it. If this request is reaching to your apache then there has to be entries both in access.log and error.log (even with 404).

Comment: 'page not found' is displaying by wordpress.

Comment: I am not asking about wordpress actually. I like to know what log files are saying at apache level.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting that specific rule just below the `RewriteBase /` rule? I think the other rules are already doing stuff causing your last one to be ignored.

Comment: that helped. but again (sorry) `RewriteRule ^foo/test$ /bar [L,R=301]` is not redirecting, I have folder named 'foo' but not test.